# rqt - python: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :0.0

Tags: ros-kinetic, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am learning ROS Kinetic by following the tutorials. I am running Ubuntu on Windows 10 and using Xming for GUI. All was going good until I reached **Using rqt_console and roslaunch** tutorial. When I entered following command

```
    rosrun rqt_logger_level rqt_logger_level
```

It worked fine for the first time. But when I closed the window and ran the same command again I  got the following error:-

**python: Fatal IO error 2 (No such file or directory) on X server :0.0.**

Later I found that any command involving rqt gives me the exact same error. However everything else including graphical programs and widgets are running absolutely fine.

I have tried removing rqt and reinstalling but nothing helps.

```
    pyhton -V
```

gives me Python 2.7.12

Can anyone please help with this problem. Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300329/rqt----python:-fatal-io-error-2-(no-such-file-or-directory)-on-x-server-:0.0./) by [HussainNiazi120](https://answers.ros.org/users/36950/hussainniazi120/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-08-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ok. so after struggling for a few hours after this post I checked out rqt -h which showed me all available options including **--clear-config**. which is suppose to clear the configuration (including all perspectives and plugin settings). So I did this:-

```
rqt --clear-config
```

and then

```
rqt_graph --clear-config
```

and one of these did the trick. Hope this helps someone.

---

Originally posted by [HussainNiazi120](https://answers.ros.org/users/36950/hussainniazi120/) with karma: 26 on 2018-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0